# is any way to check jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js is loaded or not in page using java script or jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ajaxform

How to check Js jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js is loaded or not in my page by using jquery or java script code, i am facing problem of multiple submit ajax form in partial view of MVC.

Comment: Look in the HTML source for a `<script>` tag in the page that has that file set as its `src`. Or if you have bundling enabled, check which bundle it's in an look in the source for a reference to that bundle.

Comment: thanks for this but i want know about it by code of java script or jquery

Comment: That seems like a pointless request - if you need the file then it should be added. Coding to deal with a missing file seems moot.

Comment: yes that right but in my project i have find multiple JS file loaded in page so i want to prevent this by code if its possible

Comment: In which case you should prevent those multiple files from being added to the page. Using JS as a crutch to work around that problem is a bad idea.

Comment: I am agree with you. But i need temporary solution if its possible and feasible

Answer (score 1):

if you adding the script locally then add some unique text in the end of that file like "jsfile_included" and on the page where you want to load that js file you can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).load(function(){
   var x=$("body").html();
   if(x.indexOf("jsfile_included")!=-1);
    {
           alert("js file included");
    }
    else alert("not included");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Appreciated you answer and approach but its not meet my requirement and its not work if js is included in page using CDN path

Comment: @RajdipKhavad you can add "unobtrusiveAjaxClick" text to check your cdn link is included or not.